# Javascript Set with Array Values

Tags: javascript, set

Is there a way to use arrays as values in a javascript Set?

Example:

```
s = new Set()
s.add([1,2])
s.has([1,2]) // -> false
s.add(1)
s.has(1)  // -> true
```

Presumably, the case with the array returns false because it's looking at the references and not the actual values of the arrays. Is there a way to do this operation so that `s.has([1,2])` returns `true`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use json as key.

```
s = new Set()
s.add(JSON.stringify([1,2]))
s.has(JSON.stringify([1,2])) // true
```

Comment: This works, but I'm just going to wait a bit to see if there's any other ideas before accepting it. More specifically, I'm curious if there's something similar to python's `tuple` which is passed by value rather than reference.

Answer (score 1):

You have to be carefull here, cause Set.has compares objects (here arrays) by reference, so it should look like this:

`var a = [1,2];
var s = new Set([a]);
s.has(a); // -> true`

That will work, but i would wrap Set with my own prototype for not iterating each time through set:

```
           function compareByValue(pool, needle){
                var search = [];
                pool.forEach(function(value) {
                    search.push(value.toString());
                });
                return search.indexOf(needle.toString()) !== -1;
            }
            compareByValue(s, [1,2]); // -> true
```

Comment: Right, but I want to check by value.